# Printing a range of numbers using configurable worker threads

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I have written code to print a range of numbers using multi-threaded programming.  It takes in the number of threads to spawn as input.

It is working fine and giving the expected results. I just wanted you to check it and see if the code can be written a bit more efficiently.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include <windows.h>


 void print(LPVOID );


 struct range
 {
  int start;
  int end;
  int threadnum;
 };


   void print(LPVOID param)
   {

     struct range *ptr=(struct range *)(param);
     for(int i=ptr->start;i<=ptr->end;i++)
     printf("\n Thread %d printed %d",ptr->threadnum,i);

   }


 int main()
 {

         int start,end,range,split;
         int threadcount=0;

         printf("\n Enter the start range :");
         scanf_s(" %d",&start);

         printf("\n Enter the End Range : ");
         scanf_s("%d",&end);

         printf("\n Enter the number of threads : ");
         scanf_s("%d",&threadcount);

         struct range **ptr;

         ptr = (struct range **)malloc(threadcount*sizeof(struct range *));

         if(ptr==NULL)
         {
           printf("\n Could not allocate memory for struct range * pointer array ");
           free(ptr);
           return 1;
         }

         DWORD  *ThreadId;
         ThreadId=(DWORD *)malloc(threadcount*sizeof(DWORD));
         if(ThreadId==NULL)
         { 
            printf("\n Could not allocate memory for DWORD * pointer array ");
            free(ThreadId);
            return 1;
         }

         HANDLE  *hThreadArray;
         hThreadArray=(HANDLE *)malloc(threadcount*sizeof(HANDLE));
         if(hThreadArray==NULL)
         { 
            printf("\n Could not allocate memory for hThreadArray * pointer array ");
            free(hThreadArray);
            return 1;
         }

         range=end-start+1;

         split=(range/threadcount);

         for(int i=0;i<threadcount;i++)
         {
                    ptr[i]=(struct range *)malloc(sizeof(struct range));
        if(ptr[i]==NULL)
        {
            free(ptr[i]);
        }
        if(split%2==0) // if the split is even then calculated the start    and end range for the worker threads as below
        {

         if(i==0)
         {
            start=start;
            end=start+split-1;
            ptr[i]->start=start;
            ptr[i]->end=end;
            ptr[i]->threadnum=i;


           hThreadArray[i] = CreateThread(NULL,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)print,ptr[i],0,&ThreadId[i]);
           if(hThreadArray[i]==NULL)
           { 
              CloseHandle(hThreadArray[i]);
           }


         }
         else
         {
            start=end+1;
            end=start+split-1;
            ptr[i]->start=start;
            ptr[i]->end=end;
            ptr[i]->threadnum=i;
            hThreadArray[i] = CreateThread(NULL,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)print,ptr[i],0,&ThreadId[i]);
            if(hThreadArray[i]==NULL)
            { 
              CloseHandle(hThreadArray[i]);
            }
         }
    }
        else
        {
            if(i==0)
            {
             start=start;
             end=start+split;
             ptr[i]->start=start;
             ptr[i]->end=end;
             ptr[i]->threadnum=i;


             hThreadArray[i] = CreateThread(NULL,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)print,ptr[i],0,&ThreadId[i]);
             if(hThreadArray[i]==NULL)
             { 
              CloseHandle(hThreadArray[i]);
             }


         }
          else
          {
             start=end+1;
             end=start+split-1;
             ptr[i]->start=start;
             ptr[i]->end=end;
             ptr[i]->threadnum=i;
             hThreadArray[i] = CreateThread(NULL,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)print,ptr[i],0,&ThreadId[i]);
             if(hThreadArray[i]==NULL)
             { 
               CloseHandle(hThreadArray[i]);
             }
         }
     }
}

   WaitForMultipleObjects(threadcount, hThreadArray, TRUE, INFINITE);

   for(int i=0; i<threadcount; i++)
   {
      CloseHandle(hThreadArray[i]);
      free(ptr[i]);
   }

 }
```

Comment: Please read [this about casting the result of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 3):

- First of all, while reviewing your code the bad code formatting style really hurts my eyes. Good code formatting and indentation makes it easier to review and maintain code.
- Get rid of all unnecessary spaces and tabs.
- Your `main` function is doing many things at once. Try to break the logic in smaller modules and write function for them.
- Define your structure into one type using `typedef`. The code below

  ```
  struct range
  {
   int start;
   int end;
   int threadnum;
  };
  ```

  should be like

  ```
  typedef struct range
  {
   int start;
   int end;
   int threadnum;
  }Range;
  ```

  So you can just use `Range` instead of `struct range` everytime.

  Then

  ```
  struct range *ptr=(struct range *)(param);
  ```

  will be something like

  ```
  Range *ptr = (Range *)(param);
  ```
- Keep one space both side of operators (`=`,`==`).
- Your `main` function should return `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `return 0`.

Comment: Good points. About casting you should also read the link in my comment on the question.